# Can't change minutes when using setTime with DateTimeImmutable in php

Tags: php

Can't change minutes when using setTime with DateTimeImmutable in php

php: 7.2

os: ubuntu 18.04

```
<?php

$now = new DateTimeImmutable();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:m-s')."\n";
// -> 2020-03-25 08:03-22
$at10am = $now->setTime(10, 0, 0);
echo $at10am->format('Y-m-d H:m-s')."\n";
// -> 2020-03-25 10:03-00
```

Comment: It's `H:i:s`, not `H:m:s`, you're displaying the month, not the minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's H:i:s, not H:m:s, I'm displaying the month, not the minutes. Thanks to Nick

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy ;)

```
$now = (new \DateTimeImmutable('now'))->setTime(10, 0, 0);
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```